# Adding a value to a bundle in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bundle

I was wondering how I can add an int to a bundle and pass it to the next view that I am calling.

What I am trying to do is click an item on a UITableView and that will call the next .m file and pass the int that pertains to a document that I will be looking up online. This document has a specific id and without passing it to the next view I will not be able to get the list that I need to compile and show on the next UITableView.

Comment: Did you create a UITableViewController subclass for both the initial table view and the second table view?

Comment: Yes. What I ended up doing was calling the global class earlier then I wanted to but I still would like to better understand how to pass variables if I do not have a global class to lean on.

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying the next view?  Can you not just add an instance variable to the view to be called?

```
View2 *view = [[View2 alloc] init]];
[view setSpecificId:myId];
display the view....
```

Comment: This is how I am calling the next UITableViewController which works. I am just not sure how to fill the bundle. I now use a global variable. I can load the view up with an int and then just call it from the next UITableViewController? If so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: [self presentModalViewController:showDocumentList animated:YES];

Comment: showDocumentList = [[DocumentContent alloc]initWithNibName:@"DocumentContent" bundle:nil];

Comment: Sorry about the multiple post the last two are in reverse order and I meant to copy and past the whole thing but did not see that it was missing most of the message.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by fill the bundle?  Are you using  NSBundle and you want to modify that? The general pattern I'm describing here is create an instance variable in the second controller, make sure you set that value after you create the new controller (like shown above) and then reference the instance variable in your second controller.

Comment: I was thinking about modifying the NSBundle.